# R - distinct value columns by group dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following DataFrame, (this is only the first 10 rows).

```
   date_fichier pitd   pce   frequence date_debut segment profil   car    b1    b2    b3     s1     s2     s3
          <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 201901030315 GD0991 0110~ 1M        2019-01-02 RES     P012    9253     2     2     1 5.72e6 5.72e6 5.54e6
 2 201901030315 GD0991 0115~ 1M        2019-01-02 RES     P011     419     1     1     1 8.02e3 8.02e3 1.90e5
 3 201901030315 GD0991 0117~ 6M        2019-01-02 RES     P012   12226     2     2     1 5.72e6 5.72e6 5.54e6
 4 201901030315 GD0991 0119~ 6M        2019-01-02 RES     P012   11912     2     2     1 5.72e6 5.72e6 5.54e6
 5 201901030315 GD0991 0121~ 1M        2019-01-02 RES     P012   15378     2     2     1 5.72e6 5.72e6 5.54e6
 6 201901030315 GD0991 0121~ 6M        2019-01-02 NRES    P012   42220     2     2     1 5.72e6 5.72e6 5.54e6
 7 201901030315 GD1007 0126~ 6M        2019-01-02 RES     P012    6326     1     1     1 2.48e5 2.48e5 5.54e6
 8 201901030315 GD0991 0127~ 1M        2019-01-02 RES     P011      21     1     1     1 8.02e3 8.02e3 1.90e5
 9 201901030315 GD0991 0129~ 1M        2019-01-02 RES     P012    9645     2     2     1 5.72e6 5.72e6 5.54e6
10 201901030315 GD0991 0129~ 6M        2019-01-02 RES     P012   10673     2     2     1 5.72e6 5.72e6 5.54e6
```

My profil column ranges from P011 to P019. My b1, b2, b3 columns range from 1 to 7 each for each profile. This means that P011 has a b1 ranging from 1 to 7, b2 and b3 also range from 1 to 7. Other profiles also have the same ranges of b1, b2 and b3.

As you can see for example in the head above The 1st, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th row have a profile of P012 , but their b1 is the same, all of them have a b1 of 2.

I want a DataFrame that for each profile I would get one distinct b1, b2 and b3.

I tried:

```
f %>%
     group_by(profil) %>%
     distinct(b1, b2, b3, .keep_all =T) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     dplyr::select(profil, b1, b2, b3 , s1, s2, s3) %>%
     arrange(profil)

  profil    b1    b2    b3      s1      s2      s3
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 P011       1     1     1    8018    8018  189985
2 P011       2     2     1  181967  181967  189985
3 P012       2     2     1 5715390 5715390 5544269
4 P012       1     1     1  247879  247879 5544269
5 P012       2     2     2 5715390 5715390  419000
```

But as you can see I get for example the same b3 in for P011 in line 1 and 2.

I want to have:

```
  profil    b1    b2    b3      
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   
1 P011       1     1     1   
2 P011       2     2     2  
3 P012       1     1     1  
5 P012       2     2     2
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "' for each profile I would get one distinct b1, b2 and b3."  For each profile, there are 7 * 7 * 7 combinations for b1, b2, and b3. What do you want to select from that?

Comment: ok edited some rabdom characters for the SO god

Comment: Do you mean you want to `filter()` dataset for rows having `b1==b2` and `b2==b3` ?

Comment: You sample data doesn't have a `P011` row where `b1 b2 b3` is `2 2 2`, but your desired result does have such a row. Where does it come from? Do you just want to make one if it isn't there?

Comment: Can you provide your sample data with only relevant columns using `dput` so that it is clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good first attempt. My guess is you are misusing `distinct`. The easiest way I have found to use it is `distinct(dataframe)` to return all the distinct rows in your dataframe.

This gives you the following approach:

```r
f %>%
  select(profil, b1, b2, b3) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(profil, b1, b2, b3)
```

Alternatively, suppose you wanted to count all the duplicates, or get the largest s1 values for every combination of profil, b1, b2, and b3. Then your code would look like this:

```r
f %>%
  group_by(profil, b1, b2, b3) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            largest_s1 = max(s1),
            .groups = "drop") %>% # equivalent to upgroup
  arrange(profil, b1, b2, b3)
```